# Powershell correct encoding of exe-output

Tags: powershell, encoding

I googled a lot, but I didn't find a solution for my problem. I want to call an exe from powershell and capture the output. This output I want to display correctly in the console and write it to a file:

```
$output = & ".\myExe.exe" $path
Write-Host $output
$output | Out-File -Append -Encoding UTF8 -filepath $destFile
```

This works only for non special chars. But if the output contains e.g. a Umlaut (ä,ö,ü) it does not work. Then I get something like this: õ÷³

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: This should work. Maybe the file already exists and use a diffrent encoding. Delete the `$destFile` and try again.

Comment: deleting $destFile does not help.

Answer (score 3):

I solved similar issues with `git` output using

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

UPDATE

In fact, I change the encoding temporarily just in order to call `git`

```
function Invoke-Git($Command) {
    ${*OutputEncoding} = [Console]::OutputEncoding
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
    try {
        . $Command
        if ($LASTEXITCODE) {Write-Error "Exit code: $LASTEXITCODE. Command: $Command" -ErrorAction 1}
    }
    finally {
        [Console]::OutputEncoding = ${*OutputEncoding}
    }
}
```

Thus, if changing the encoding makes issues for other commands then try to use this approach.

Comment: this results in an error:
Write-Host : The Win32 internal error "A device attached to the system is not functioning" 0x1F occurred while writing
to the console output buffer at the current cursor position. Contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.

Comment: Then try to change the encoding just for a call, then restore it. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. Let's have next testing script, where simple console application `CliParser.exe` echoes command line arguments (written in `C`, inspired [here](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINARGV))

```
$destFile="d:\test\35909655-UTF8.txt"
Remove-Item $destFile
###
### [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
###
$output = & "d:\bat\CliParser.exe" äöü
$output | Out-File -Append -Encoding UTF8 -filepath $destFile
"{0} {1} {2}" -f "Console code pages", [System.Console]::OutputEncoding.WindowsCodePage,
                                       [System.Console]::OutputEncoding.CodePage
"{0} {1} {2}" -f "System  code pages", [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.WindowsCodePage, 
                                       [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.CodePage
```

**Output** under various circumstances shows discrepancy in code pages; output file is `UTF-8` encoded so `get-content` would display it correctly regardless of active code page (see `chcp 437` below):

```
==> chcp 850
Active code page: 850

==> powershell D:\PShell\SO\35909655.ps1
Console code pages 1252 850
System  code pages 1250 1250

==> powershell get-content "d:\test\35909655-UTF8.txt"
param 0 = D:\bat\CliParser.exe
param 1 = õ÷³

==> chcp 1250
Active code page: 1250

==> powershell D:\PShell\SO\35909655.ps1
Console code pages 1250 1250
System  code pages 1250 1250

==> chcp 437
Active code page: 437

==> powershell get-content "d:\test\35909655-UTF8.txt"
param 0 = D:\bat\CliParser.exe
param 1 = äöü

==>
```

Please forget that in above output appears code page `1252` (it's only *my* default).

**Answer**: To treat the case in Powershell script, use (remove leading `###`)

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
```

Comment: So we can use both `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` and `chcp`? I got it working with the first one not the second though. Thought it should set the same thing in via Windows API. What's your point?