# PowerShell, Cannot remove BOM from file

Tags: powershell, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have been trying dozens of different options for an hour, strip the BOM, set file to `ascii / oem / utf8`, followed the ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124466/how-can-i-redirect-input-in-powershell-without-a-bom), but the BOM remains in all cases. I'm a bit stumped.

Firstly, I always `Remove-Item` with `-Force` to make sure that there is no remnant of the file before I start, then I pipe some simple text into a newly created file:

```
$out = @'
####################
#
# Shortcuts
#
####################
'@
$OutputEncoding = [Text.Utf8Encoding]::new($false)
$out | Out-File -FilePath $ShortcutNotes -Force -Encoding utf8
# I have tried utf8 / oem / ascii
```

This part of text always looks fine in the final file, no strangeness.

But then I pipe some fairly innocuous output from some operations into the file and everything goes wrong:

```
# Some operations before here, but this is the important line:
$AppName = (($AppShortcut -split "\\")[-1] -split "\.")[0]
"App added: $AppName" | Out-File -FilePath $ShortcutNotes -Append
```

End result, I get UTF8 with BOM when I open the file in Notepad++ and it looks like this (header part is always fine, then the rest has the NULLs):

```
####################
#
# Shortcuts
#
####################

A[NULL]p[NULL]p[NULL] [NULL]a[NULL]d[NULL]d[NULL]e[NULL]d[NULL]:[NULL] [NULL]G[NULL]o[NULL]o[NULL]g[NULL]l[NULL]e[NULL] [NULL]C[NULL]h[NULL]r[NULL]o[NULL]m[NULL]e
```

I've even tried to strip BOM afterwards:

```
(Get-Cotent $ShortcutNotes) -replace "\xEF\xBB\xBF", "" | Set-Content $ShortcutNotes
```

All of the above fails, and the file is always UTF8 with BOM and always garbled as above.

I've run out of things to try, can anyone see what I am doing wrong that my output is always garbled in this way?

**Update**
The operations that I'm doing after the header are very simple, but maybe they will suggest what is going wrong. This is a snippet from the function that is called and that writes to the file. It seems to be this that is causing the issue, but I don't know how/why:

```
function Setup-AppAndShortcut ($AppFolder, $ZipFile, $AppExe, $AppShortcut) {
    if (Test-Path $AppExe) {
        $ShortcutFile = $AppShortcut
        $Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
        $Shortcut.TargetPath = $AppExe
        $Shortcut.Save()
        [string]$AppName = (($AppShortcut -split "\\")[-1] -split "\.")[0]
        "App added: $AppName" | Out-File -FilePath $ShortcutNotes -Append   # These are the lines that always end up garbled with NULLs in my final output.
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596984/1701026)

Comment: Thanks, sadly not, just tried it now, I will update my question with information about the operations that I'm making, maybe you will see something that I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: I noticed that after I use your technique, regardless of whether I use `-Encoding ascii` or `utf8` or `oem` when I open the final file in Notepad++, it always reports as `ANSI` (whereas it would previously report as `UTF8 with BOM`, but the output is still full of `NULL` between every character.

Comment: "*it always reports as `ANSI`*", that is ok as it can't determine the encoding from the content (all 7 bit chars and there is no BOM defined ). For what you doing with `$AppName = (($AppShortcut -split "\\")[-1] -split "\.")[0]`, the output encoding is related to the encoding set by the host, see ((Windows) PowerShell console/ide/vscode), see: [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/1701026). Try: `$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding`

Comment: What is actually in `$AppShortcut`? (that is where your issue originates, it apparently outputs a different encoding than you intent to use. Just `'Test' | Out-File -FilePath $ShortcutNotes -Append` works fine for me). See also: [Powershell correct encoding of exe-output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35911310/1701026)

Comment: In PowerShell 7.x `Out-File` defaults to writing `utf8NoBOM`. If you're using PowerShell 5.x, then the default output is `Unicode` (==> UTF-16LE)

Comment: Out-file -append can mix encodings.  I prefer add-content.

Comment: I pointed this out three years ago:  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9423

Comment: Replacing `Out-File` by `Add-Content` to stop `Out-File` from blindly altering encoding completely resolved the issue, thanks (I have been scratching my head at this issue for more than a week). I will avoid `Out-File` whenever possible in future as its behaviour (even though matching POSIX) is strange and almost always **not** what I want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use add-content instead of out-file -append, which can mix different encodings in the same file.  Bug report:

[out-file -append (or >>) can mix two encodings in the same file · Issue #9423 · PowerShell · GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9423)